# Fix impossible deletion

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign

When [one of my questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219301/n-dimensional-pyramid-numbers) got closed as a duplicate (correctly), I got this screen.

[image: duplicate]

Then, when I clicked the delete button, this showed up:

[image: confirm]

Then when I confirmed, I got this:

[image]

What's the point of showing the delete button if I'm not allowed to use it? It's redundant and annoying - is this intentional in some bizarre way, or is it a bug? Whichever, can we please fix it by not showing the delete button?

Comment: I'm willing to bet the check for whether or not deletion is allowed is done on the server-side when you try to commit the delete, since I could delete that question, for example, even though it has answers, and moving it to be checked as the page is loading in would be unnecessary, since it's just one button and doesn't really take up any space and isn't particularly annoying. If you find it particularly annoying, it might be worth raising to [the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as a feature request, but I doubt they'd invest the time into such a minor change.